# How do I send sound generated by Web Audio API from one website to another using socket.io and Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, socket.io, p5.js

I am working on an application that involves sending the sound output from a series of webpages to a central page that plays all the outputs simultaneously. Right now, I'm using p5 (the Processing JavaScript library, which is basically just a wrapper on the WebAudio API), node.js, and socket.io.

I know it's possible to stream the microphone input to a server and then back to the client, but how would I do this with audio created in the browser with the WebAudio API? How do I turn the AudioContext output into binary data, stream it through the socket, and then play it back client-side? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: All of these pages would run on the same client, in the same browser?

Comment: If you already know how to use the user media audio node, it's identical to send audio from any other audio node.  And, you should elaborate more on your requirements.  Specifically, latency and audio quality.

Comment: @Bergi, the audio sent to the server will be from different websites and different clients, all summed by one server and outputted as its own website. I'm imagining it like inputs on a mixer, allowing people to collaborate together in real time.

Comment: @Brad, right now audio quality is more important than latency - looking to stream the full 44.1 kHz if I can.

Comment: @TristanRodman Sample rate isn't really relevant... the rates that come in are dictated by the browser unfortunately.  So, unless you're re-sampling, it doesn't matter so much.  It's more of a question of whether or not you use lossy compression (such as when you use WebRTC) or you send straight PCM samples (lots of flexibility, but you have to implement yourself... best quality audio though).

Comment: @Brad Got it. I played around with WebRTC implementations but ultimately settled on sending raw PCM data. Right now I'm calling createBuffer() on the AudioContext and then getChannelData() on the buffer, but when I log I'm getting zero as every number in the array (even with sound outputting through my computer speakers).

Comment: @TristanRodman Without seeing your code I wouldn't really know what to suggest.

Comment: `code`
    stream = context.createBuffer(2, 256, 41000);

    binary = {left: stream.getChannelData(0), right: stream.getChannelData(1)};

    console.log(binary.left);

    console.log(binary.right);

    socket.emit('sound', binary);

`code`
is what the draw() section of my p5 sketch looks like right now. where context is defined earlier as the audiocontext for that window.